# JSON.stringify(objExtraParam) giving wrong date

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a javascript object as below.

`var obj = { pageSize:"25",asOfDate:"Thu Sep 25 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014"};`

when i stringify it,

`var d = JSON.stringify(obj);`

its giving me result as

`{"pageSize":"25","asOfDate":"2014-09-24T18:30:00Z"}`

what could be the reason that its giving date `2014-09-24` than `2014-09-25` ?

EDIT:

My deployment server is located in US (Eastern Time UTC -5:00).when i check the site from my local machine in india its giving me date as `24 Sept 2014`

Comment: is asOfDate is an Date object? or a string?

Comment: Surely it is a date, this could be caused by UTC conversion

Comment: does `JSON.stringify` automatically converts date to UTC?

Comment: use toString on it (before saving it) and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

`UTC+0530` declares a UTC time offset.  Seems that `5:30` is around the [India or Sri Lanka area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B05:30).

`"2014-09-24T18:30:00Z"` is the same as `"Thu Sep 25 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014"` in two different formats.  The `Z` in the first format is resolving to UTC (GMT) time, which in this case is `-5:30`.  So `18:30` is `24:00 - 5:30`.

So, if you are `stringify`-ing in a timezone that is negative offset (say in the [United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9208:00) `UTC−08:00`) then it could push the date back by one day when parsing.

I think this is what you are seeing.

Related SO Question: [JSON Stringify changes time of date because of UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486476/json-stringify-changes-time-of-date-because-of-utc)

Comment: but i'm `stringify`-ing in timezone `5:30` still its giving date back by one day

Comment: `"2014-09-24T18:30:00Z"` is the same as `Thu Sep 25 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014`.  The `Z` indicates that it is UTC (GMT) time.

Comment: checkout the other SO question I refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486476/json-stringify-changes-time-of-date-because-of-utc

Comment: The server could always pass UTC.  However, that is probably not an option.  Or pass a string from the server and then handle the parse yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    var obj = { pageSize:"25",asOfDate:"Thu Sep 25 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014"};
    obj.asOfDate = reverseUTC(obj.asOfDate);
    var d = JSON.stringify(obj);

    function reverseUTC(updatedDate) {
       if ($.isEmptyObject(updatedDate)) {
          var offset = updatedDate.getTimezoneOffset();

           var currentDateTime = new Date();
           updatedDate.setHours((currentDateTime.getHours() * 60 + currentDateTime.getMinutes() - offset) / 60);
           updatedDate.setMinutes((currentDateTime.getHours() * 60 + currentDateTime.getMinutes() - offset) % 60);
    return updatedDate;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard format for passing dates in JSON, so `JSON.stringify` is just calling the default `date.prototype.toString()` method and that is taking the timezone into account.

You need to ensure that the date is converted into a string to your particular requirements and only convert to JSON format.