# Date in response JSON is different than in database

Tags: json, sails.js

I have sails.js application. 
When I add record to my MySQL database there is field createdAt - type dateTime.
In MySql console createdAt value looks like `Wed Mar 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100`
When I try to get this data as JSON using sails.js controller  I get 
`2015-03-24T23:00:00.000Z`   - which is 1 hour elier?
My system time zone is GMT +1.
How can I get the same time in db and JSON rsponse?

```
   'list': function (req, res, next) {

 Tests.find().exec(function (err, tests) {
   if (err) res.json({ error: 'DB error' }, 500);
   if (tests) {
     _.each(tests, function (data) {
       console.log("Date: " + JSON.stringify(data.createdAt)+"   "+data.createdAt);
     })
     res.status(200).json(tests);
   }
 });
```

And console output is:

```
 Date: "2015-03-10T14:28:51.000Z"   Tue Mar 10 2015 15:28:51 GMT+0100
Date: "2015-03-16T10:25:34.000Z"   Mon Mar 16 2015 11:25:34 GMT+0100
Date: "2015-03-16T11:27:23.000Z"   Mon Mar 16 2015 12:27:23 GMT+0100
Date: "2015-03-16T11:33:39.000Z"   Mon Mar 16 2015 12:33:39 GMT+0100
Date: "2015-03-16T11:34:41.000Z"   Mon Mar 16 2015 12:34:41 GMT+0100
Date: "2015-03-16T12:13:21.000Z"   Mon Mar 16 2015 13:13:21 GMT+0100
Date: "2015-03-16T13:54:03.000Z"   Mon Mar 16 2015 14:54:03 GMT+0100
```

It all happends while converting to JSON - still dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Sounds like something's applying the time zone offset twice. You might want to check that by temporarily going into a different time zone, e.g. for the US. Next, post the code - we don't know whether the problem is when you fetch the data from the database, or when it's serialized as part of the response.

Comment: the data is looks ok, i think the problem is in the print that are in different format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stackoverflow question 1486476][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486476/json-stringify-changes-time-of-date-because-of-utc

Comment: It is similar, but solution dosent fit here. My server and client is in the same time zone and when I send resultset from query in response as json I dont want to iterate over resultset to convert all date fileds.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify(data.createdAt)` is equal to `data.createdAt.toJSON()` and it is equal to `data.createdAt.toISOString()`

`data.createdAt` is equal to `data.createdAt.toString()`

the time value is equal; `toString()` returns it according your time zone, while `toISOString()` in GMT.

to get the Date from JSON string use conversion function as 2nd parameter of `JSON.parse()`, you can use the regexp `rx = /([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{3})Z/` to check the date ISO format and then convert it to date `d = new Date(str)`

Comment: new Date('2015-03-16T21:10:30.000Z') or new Date(1426540230000) create UTC date 2015-03-16 21:10:30; new Date(2015,2,16,21,10,30,0) creates your local date 2015-03-16 21:10:30 GMT+-your time zone; new Date() creates your current local date

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of createdAt in your Mysql database? Is it Date? If yes try setting it to varchar. And if you need to manipulate it or format it you can use moment js.