# How do i tell javascript to not convert date object to UTC while serializing

Tags: javascript, json, date

I want

```
JSON.stringify(new Date());
```

to return local date. How can I do that?

Comment: *"and also is there any datatype in javascript for time less date and dateless time ?"* Ask **one** question per question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Stringify changes time of date because of UTC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486476/json-stringify-changes-time-of-date-because-of-utc)

Comment: @AleksandarMatic Is there any Object/Datatype in javascript for date without time like java.sql.Date

Comment: No, there isn't. T.J.'s answer below can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to write a *replacer* function and pass that to `JSON.stringify`. The replacer would detect dates and output the format you want for them.

```
JSON.stringify(new Date(), function(key, value) {
    var rawValue = this[key];
    if (rawValue instanceof Date) {
        return /*...whatever format you want using `rawValue`...*/;
    }
    return value;
});
```

There I've made it an inline function, but of course you can make it a named function that you reuse.

Example:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Date(), function(key, value) {
  var rawValue = this[key];
  if (rawValue instanceof Date) {
    return "Your string here for " + rawValue;
  }
  return value;
}));
```