# JSON.stringify returns wrong value for the Date Object

Tags: javascript, json, date

the below code returns one day earlier,

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(new Date("02/02/1997"));
alert(myJSON);
```

myJSON variables returns "*1997-02-01T18:30:00.000Z*"

Why its returning wrong value.

Here, what does the meaning of "*T18:30:00.000Z*"

Is there any other way of converts the Date object to the String.

Comment: Its converting local Date object to UTC date

Comment: Try JSON.stringfy(new Date("02/02/1997").toDateString());

Comment: what you're trying to achieve, your original data seems to be a string  "02/02/1997"?

Comment: It's not the wrong date. If your timezone offset is +05:30 it's the correct date and transferable to any other system. Probably a duplicate of [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript?s=1|4.5819)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Stringify changes time of date because of UTC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486476/json-stringify-changes-time-of-date-because-of-utc)

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```js
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(new Date("02/02/1997").toLocaleString());
    alert(myJSON);
```

Comment: Even if parsing the string produces the correct date (which is problematic), the result of *toLocaleString* is entirely implementation dependent and the string produced by one host may not be parsed correctly by another.

Answer (score 0):

It is converting your Date object to UTC date.

You should convert Date object to String value using predefined methods of Date Object. Like:

```
JSON.stringify(new Date("02/02/1997").toLocaleString());

JSON.stringify(new Date("02/02/1997").toDateString()); // to get date portion
```

Comment: No, don't do that. Parsing a string like "02/02/1997" is not a good idea. Also, the result of *toLocaleString* is entirely implementation dependent and the string created by one host may not be parseable by another.

Answer (score -3):

Recommend you take a look at [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). The framework provides a very nice API for:

> Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in JavaScript.

Convert your date into the desired string format and then [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: I don't think suggesting a library is appropriate for answering a question about JavaScript's standard library

Comment: Given the endless fun of JavaScript date handling thought I'd drop it in to the conversation. Sorry for the static.

Comment: I totally agree that moment.js is great, it's just not something that's relevant as to how JavaScript's standard library works.