# MySQL 5.7 JSON automatically formats time

Tags: json, mysql-5.7

Does anyone know why the function JSON_OBJECT formats TIME-data automatically?
When I do the following:

```
SELECT
        JSON_OBJECT(
            'Time_Transformed', TIME('11:42:00')
        ) AS myJson,
        TIME('11:42:00') AS `Time_Raw`
```

The result is:

```
myJson: {"Time_Transformed": "11:42:00.000000"}
Time_Raw: 11:42:00
```

Comment: What do you actually want? You want to know why this happening or how to fix this?

Comment: I think this may answer why it does this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1488415/6530134

Comment: @TimothyG. it is not even MySQL.

Comment: @Ahmad I want to fix it

Comment: By the way, good question. I've upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL recognizes TIME values in several formats.

If you want to omit the fractional part, you can use this.

```
SELECT
    JSON_OBJECT(
        'Time_Transformed',  TIME_FORMAT(TIME('11:42:00'), '%H %i %s')
    ) AS myJson
```

Comment: Is there a way to stop MySQL from doing that in the first place? I mean the formatting only happens when using JSON_OBJECT()

Comment: I don't know if it is possible. But why don't you use TIME_FORMAT() as in the answer?

Comment: Because I have many columns and values with the type "TIME" and dont want to search for every single one of those

Comment: I think it is the only possible solution. Try search and replace.