# why JSON.stringify change time when i parse json into it

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

why when i convert time JSON.stringify why my time change please help me how to handle this please anyone help me , and how to direct json  transfer Code behind C# variable

```
subject_end: Thu Jan 01 1970 09:00:00 
After JSON.stringift
"subject_start":"1970-01-01T03:00:00.000Z" 
i don't know why this happen

     $scope.Savesujects = function (item, event) {
                            console.log($scope.moreadditems);
                            var getjsonvar = JSON.stringify($scope.moreadditems);
                            console.log(getjsonvar);
                            var ssa = String(getjsonvar);
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "classschedule.aspx/savesubhects",

                                data: JSON.stringify({ jsonstring: ssa }),
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (msg) {
                                    alert(msg.d);

                                },
                                error: function (msg) {
                                    alert(msg.d);
                                }
                            });
                        }

//CODE BEHINED 

    [WebMethod]
            public static string savesubhects(string jsonstring)
            {}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: it's converting it to UTC time.   No ide awhy you scribbled over the time offset as that's the important bit

Comment: if you look on stack overflow, plenty of questions on asking how to seralize  in many different formats

Answer (score 0):

JSON considers date time in UTC.
This is why you are seeing the datetime value changed when you call JSON.stringify

Either you can store this date time as UTC or do the required culture specifc conversion at C# end.

Comment: how to solve this problem... ??any idea ?? i want time... for saving in database

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure because you scribbled out the time zone (why?) but I think it says +05:00 - It looks like you are seeing the exact same time represented two different ways. Once in the local time zone (+5 hours) and one in UTC time without timezone added. See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486476/json-stringify-changes-time-of-date-because-of-utc) for the same issue

EDIT: Generally the best practice for time is to handle and store it in UTC time, and convert it to the local timezone when displaying. For websites you can use a framework like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to do the conversions simply

Comment: how to solve this problem... ??any idea ?? i want time... for saving in database