# Moment js - get date without considering time zone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I did read different StackOverflow posts and they suggested to use .utc from moment but it doesn't work

**Note:** I am on PST zone

```
const start = '2018-06-10T21:00:00-04:00';
const end = '2018-06-10T23:00:00-04:00';
const noconversion = moment.utc(start).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
const converted = moment(end).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

**Current output:**

noconversion - 2018-06-11

converted - 2018-06-11

**Output expected:**
06/10/2018 just fetch date from date provided

[CODEPEN Link](https://codepen.io/snehav27/pen/ZjJbMW)

```
const date = '2018-06-16T00:00:00-04:00';
const oldConversion = moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
const newConversion = moment.parseZone(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
 
alert('********oldConversion**********'+ oldConversion);
alert('********newConversion**********'+ newConversion);
```

Comment: Why not make a custom function to do it? Does it really have to be with moment.js?

Comment: custom function, I also want to format the date.

Comment: I think: new Date also considers timezone. How can I make custom function, With all the cases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Stringify changes time of date because of UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486476/json-stringify-changes-time-of-date-because-of-utc)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried parseZone?

```
moment.parseZone(end).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

That should keep your UTC offset applied. You can then also calculate the UTC offset, if you wanted to save that:

```
moment.parseZone(end).format('MM/DD/YYYY').utcOffset();
```

Comment: I did try it I did had the same issue in one of the time zone. I will check again

Comment: @KamalakannanJ from https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/ seems like there is some conversion going on

Comment: I did take this approach as it resolves EST/PST issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm suggesting will ignore the timezone itself. It always take only the date. It might be a complex way to do it, but it always works for you.

```
const start = '2018-06-10T21:00:00-04:00'.split('-').slice(0, -1).join('-');
const end = '2018-06-10T23:00:00-04:00'.split('-').slice(0, -1).join('-');
const noconversion = moment(start).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
const converted = moment(end).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: What if the timezone is not provided?  This will fail in that case. I wouldn't take that risk. I would never muck with the string provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore timezone then why not from the string itself? This is just an out of the box thinking.

```
function convertToDate(date_string) {
    var date = date_string.indexOf('T') > -1 ? new Date(date_string.split('T')[0]) : date_string.indexOf(' ') > -1 ? new Date(date_string.split(' ')[0]) : new Date(date_string.substring(0,10));
    return (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
}
```

OR

```
function convertToDate(date_string) {
    var date = date_string.indexOf('T') > -1 ? date_string.split('T')[0].split('-') : date_string.indexOf(' ') > -1 ? date_string.split(' ')[0].split('-') : date_string.substring(0,10).split('-');
    return date[1] + "/" + date[2] + "/" + date[0];
}

const start = '2018-06-10T21:00:00-04:00';
const converted = convertToDate(start);
```

Comment: What if the timezone is not provided?  This will fail in that case. I wouldn't take that risk. I would never muck with the string provided.

Comment: It won't fail even there is no timezone as I am splitting with **T** separator which is in all date standards.

Comment: Still I am afraid to use string split approach

Comment: I have added one more function which uses Date function.