# Angular date time picker display correct date time but send it - 1hour

Tags: angular, format, timezone, datetimepicker

[Here what i see when inspecting in the front during submitting the data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcBJu.png)

Here below the code i'am using in the html page:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h2>Nouveau Client </h2>
          </td>
          <td>
            <mat-slide-toggle (click) = "isParticulier=!isParticulier"  color="primary" style ="margin-left: 50px;"class="example-margin" >Société</mat-slide-toggle> 
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

<div>


    <div class ="col-md-6  offset-md-3" style ="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px;" >
        <form  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            <table class="input_table"   >
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="input_field" >
                        <mat-label>Code</mat-label>
                        <input readonly matInput required id ="next_Id_CLIENT"
                        ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]= "next_Id_CLIENT" name ="next_Id_CLIENT">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="input_field" >
                        <mat-label>Nom Complet</mat-label>
                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]= "client.nom_COMPLET" name ="nom_COMPLET">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="input_field">
                        <mat-label>Adresse</mat-label>
                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]= "client.adresse" name ="adresse">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="input_field">
                        <mat-label>Num. Téléphone1</mat-label>
                        <input type="number"  matInput [(ngModel)]= "client.tel_PRINCIPAL" name ="tel_PRINCIPAL">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                  
                   
                </tr>
                <tr *ngIf="!isParticulier"> 
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="input_field" >
                        <mat-label>Société</mat-label>
                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]= "client.societe" name ="societe">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="input_field">
                        <mat-label>Matricule Fiscale</mat-label>
                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]= "client.matricule_FISCALE" name ="matricule_FISCALE">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                   
                   
                </tr>
                <tr *ngIf="!isParticulier"> 
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="input_field">
                        <mat-label>Point de Contact</mat-label>
                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]= "client.point_DE_CONTACT" name ="point_DE_CONTACT">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="input_field">
                        <mat-label>Num. Téléphone2</mat-label>
                        <input type="number" matInput [(ngModel)]= "client.tel_SECONDAIRE" name ="tel_SECONDAIRE">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="input_field">

                            <input matInput  [(ngModel)]= "client.date_DE_CREATION " name ="date_DE_CREATION" 
                            [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker" placeholder="Date de Création" [formControl]="dateControl"
                            [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [disabled]="disabled">
                          
                            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="$any(picker)"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                            <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker [showSpinners]="showSpinners" [showSeconds]="showSeconds"
                              [stepHour]="stepHour" [stepMinute]="stepMinute" [stepSecond]="stepSecond" [touchUi]="touchUi"
                              [color]="color" [enableMeridian]="enableMeridian">
                            </ngx-mat-datetime-picker>                      
                          </mat-form-field>
                        <!--mat-form-field class="input_field">
                        <mat-label>Date de Création</mat-label>
                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]= "client.date_DE_CREATION" name ="date_DE_CREATION">
                        </mat-form-field-->
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="input_field">
                        <mat-label>Crée par</mat-label>
                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]= "client.cree_PAR" name ="cree_PAR">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                <div class="example-button-row" >
                    <button [disabled]="saved" mat-raised-button  type="submit" color="primary" style ="margin-right: 10px;" >Enregistrer</button>
                    <button mat-raised-button (click)="goToListeClients()">Retour</button>
                </div>
            </form>
</div >
<mat-divider style ="margin-top: 10ox;"></mat-divider>
</div>
```

The code below for the ts file:

```
        import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
    import { ThemePalette } from '@angular/material/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { Client } from '../client';
    import { ClientserviceService } from '../clientservice.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-nouveau-client',
      templateUrl: './nouveau-client.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./nouveau-client.component.css']
    })
    export class NouveauClientComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild('picker') picker: any;
      public disabled = false;
      public showSpinners = true;
      public showSeconds = true;
      public touchUi = false;
      public enableMeridian = false;
      public minDate!: moment.Moment;
      public maxDate!: moment.Moment;
      public stepHour = 1;
      public stepMinute = 1;
      public stepSecond = 1;
      public color: ThemePalette = 'primary';
        dateForm! : FormGroup;
      public options = [
        { value: true, label: 'True' },
        { value: false, label: 'False' }
      ];
      public listColors = ['primary', 'accent', 'warn'];
      public stepHours = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      public stepMinutes = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
      public stepSeconds = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
    dateControl = new FormControl;
     
      next_Id_CLIENT : number |undefined;
      client = new Client;
      saved = false;
      isParticulier = true;
      constructor(private router: Router ,private clientservice : ClientserviceService) { }
      getNextIdClient(){
        this.clientservice.getNextIdClient().subscribe((data : any[])=>{this.next_Id_CLIENT = data as any ;  console.log(this.next_Id_CLIENT)})
      }
      goToListeClients(){
        this.router.navigate(['vente/clients'])
      }
      AjoutFournisseur(){
        this.clientservice.ajoutClient(this.client).subscribe(data => {console.log(data);this.saved = true;});
      }
      onSubmit(){
         this.AjoutFournisseur()
      } 
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getNextIdClient()
      }
    
    }
```

This way the date time stored in MYSQL is wrong and i need to reformat it again using java to display it correctly in PDF reports , also it needs formatting to be displayed in Angular again.

Any advise? Thanks

Comment: Does your local time correspond to date-picker value, or the sent value?

Comment: The local time correspond to the date picker value.

Comment: Any help on this request?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in dateTimePicker but in the way you send the data to backend. JSON changes hour.
JSON uses the Date.prototype.toISOString, it doesn't represent local date.
Please refer these link : [JSON Stringify changes time of date because of UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486476/json-stringify-changes-time-of-date-because-of-utc)