# react datepicker with emailjs

Tags: reactjs, email, react-datepicker

I made reservation form. I want to send the reservation time by email using date-picker. So I received the reservation information using emailjs, but the time comes differently. I checked the console, there is no problem, but when I check the email, another time is sent. What's wrong with this?

```
import { React, useRef } from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

const Contact = () => {
  const form = useRef();
  const time = useRef();

  const { control } = useForm();
  const sendEmail = (e) => {

    const info = {
      name: form.current["name"].value,
      email: form.current["email"].value,
      phone: form.current["phone"].value,
      message: form.current["message"].value,
      size: form.current["size"].value,
      time: time.current.props.selected,
    };
    console.log("log name", form.current["name"].value);
    console.log("log email", form.current["email"].value);
    console.log("log phone", form.current["phone"].value);
    console.log("log message", form.current["message"].value);
    console.log("log size", form.current["size"].value);
    console.log("log time", time.current.props.selected);

    e.preventDefault();
    emailjs
      .send("serviceID", "templateID", info, "publicKey")
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.status, result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.status, error.text);
        }
      );
  };

  return (
    <section class="page-section" id="contact">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Reservation</h2>
        </div>

        <form id="contactForm" ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
          <div class="row align-items-stretch mb-5">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <Controller
                  control={control}
                  name="time"
                  id="time"
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <DatePicker
                      placeholderText="Select date"
                      onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}
                      selected={field.value}
                      showTimeSelect
                      dateFormat="Pp"
                      timeFormat="p"
                      //minDate={new Date()}
                      minDate={new Date()}
                      minTime={new Date().setHours(17, 0, 0, 0)}
                      maxTime={new Date().setHours(21, 0, 0, 0)}
                      ref={time}
                    />
                  )}
                />
              </div>
```

Web site
[image: web site]

Console log

[image: console log]

Email, I got different time
[image: email]

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript normally convert local timezone to UTC .
I think its the problem with UTC time sending over in the api.. you can use momentjs or i have shared the discussions , which has so many solutions for this problem..

Refer this..

[JSON Stringify changes time of date because of UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486476/json-stringify-changes-time-of-date-because-of-utc)